# Name cannot begin with the ' ' character

Tags: c#, xml, memorystream, xmltextreader

I'm parsing some XML in C#. I'm getting it from a database, and so converting it to a MemoryStream before reading it with an XmlTextReader. The problem is that I get this error: `Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20. Line 1, position 3.` Following is my XML and my code for reading it (it's coming out of the database alright, no blank first character). Any suggestions?

XML:

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<form>
   <e order="0" type="custom" name="test">
      <fi type="text" />
      <o />
   </e>
   <e order="1" type="zip" />
   <e order="2" type="state" />
</form>
```

C#:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[formXml.Length];
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(formXml);
MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(xmlStream);
while (xmlReader.Read())
{
    if (xmlReader.HasValue)
    {
        returnString += xmlReader.Depth.ToString();
    }
}
```

I thought it could be the encoding, but I've tried by UTF8 and ASCII and can't find anything.

Comment: BTW, unless you're still using .NET 1.1, you should use `XmlReader.Create()` instead of `new XmlTextReader()`.

Comment: It does not allow special character..

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, you should delete the space between <? and xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<form>
   <e order="0" type="custom" name="test">
      <fi type="text" />
      <o />
   </e>
   <e order="1" type="zip" />
   <e order="2" type="state" />
</form>
```

[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-XMLDecl)'s the relevant XML spec.

Comment: And the error message is (for once) completely spot on about the location of the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Another common source of this error is when the XmlReader attempts to read your scripts as xml.  That's a good reason to start commenting out scripts after the script tags. They will still run:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function myFunction() {
    }
    ...
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Your error message is quite explicit, you have an error at posn 3 in line 1.  Try `<?xml` -- no space.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the first space in the document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Answer (score 4):

My error in same case was that file wasn't saved as UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

You also should be carefull and avoid expressions like:

```
<e order="0" type="custom" name= "test">
```

The blank space that follows the name's equal could make your code crash

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error reading an XML file.

It turned out I had an errant < character in my file.

I was commenting out certain child nodes and when erasing one of the comment tags, I left an extra < in the file.  The error message came back "Name cannot begin with the '\r' character" and this question was the top google result for that exact search.

```
<node>
    <!-- <child /> --><
    <child />
    <child />
</node>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of errors because of this. Make sure you don't have spaces. There are two places I removed spaces that worked for me.

Was:

```
xmlns: xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

What worked:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

There was a space here too: < abc:def >. Remove all the spaces around the < and the >.

Answer (score 0):

If in SSIS, just go to Solution Explorer, select the project then select "Rebuild Solution" from the Build menu option.