# Visual Studio: Load operation failed

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin, csproj, sln-file

When I try to open [my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYBl7.png), this message is appear: 
[Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C. Line 21, position 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnHVw.png) and then 
[I can't open my project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5mF7.png)

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6648f36f-e8e0-4321-b3a9-c647b5be8a57/name-cannot-begin-with-the-character-hexadecimal-value-0x3c-line-2-position-2?forum=vssetup) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282467/name-cannot-begin-with-the-character)

Answer (score 0):

[This is what my Visual Studio looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h0MA.png)